# Jenkins pipeline: Send email at user input?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have following jenkins pipeline step which wait for user input to certain steps in release. I want to sent a email to certain person so he/she can quickly attend and decide the this input value. How to do that ?

```
stage('Promote to Production ?') {
          agent none
          steps {
                timeout(time: 60, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                    script {
                        env.RELEASE_TO_PROD = input message: 'User input required',
                            parameters: [choice(name: 'Promote to production', choices: 'no\nyes', description: 'Choose "yes" if you want to deploy this build in prduction')]
                        milestone 1
                    }
                }
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you can simply add [`mail`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#mail-mail) step to your pipeline:

```
steps {
    mail to: 'devops@company.com', subject: 'New build is waiting for your decision', body: 'Please make your decision about new build in Jenkins!'
    timeout(time: 60, unit: 'SECONDS') {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you prefer to use more powerful [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin), pipeline will be almost the same. For example, we may decide to attach build log to our mail, so pipeline will look as follows:

```
steps {
    emailext to: 'devops@company.com', subject: 'New build is waiting for your decision', body: 'Please make your decision about new build in Jenkins!', attachLog: true
    timeout(time: 60, unit: 'SECONDS') {
        // ...
    }
}
```